# Javascript map, reduce not working when implemented within object method

Tags: javascript

Based on the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234969/javascript-sum-inner-arrays-in-3d-nested-arrays) I implemented the map reduce code within an object method.

```
this.displayValueGraph = async () => {
  let scaleData = [];
  this.positions.forEach(async (pos, i) => {
    scaleData[i] = [];
    let gdata = await pos.graphData;
    gdata.option.forEach((d) => {
      scaleData[i].push(d.map((x) => x * pos.size));
    });
  });
  let out;
  if (scaleData.length == 1) {
    out = scaleData[0];
  } else {
    out = scaleData.reduce((a, b) => b.map((x, j) => x.map((v, k) => a[j][k] + v)));
  }
};
```

The code by itself works fine. I have taken the input data (above scaleData) and run it through the map reduce function and the output is as expected. But if I include it as part of this method it does nothing. It doesn't throw any errors, it simply returns an empty array.

I have tried adding an empty array as an "initial value", but it doesn't help.

Comment: `scaleData` is but an empty array by the time `out` gets reduced of it. You have to `await` for the `async` function or use a callback.

Comment: @Lain this appears to be the case.

Comment: But only indirectly. The true culprit was the first forEach loop with the await in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem appears to have been the first forEach loop, where I included an await. I replaced the `forEach` with `for in` and it solved the problem.

```
this.displayValueGraph = async () => {
  let scaleData = [];
  for (const i in this.positions) {
    const pos = this.positions[i];
    scaleData[i] = [];
    let gdata = await pos.graphData;
    gdata.option.forEach((d) => {
      scaleData[i].push(d.map((x) => x * pos.size));
    });
  }
  let out;
  if (scaleData.length == 1) {
    out = scaleData[0];
  } else {
    out = scaleData.reduce((a, b) => b.map((x, j) => x.map((v, k) => a[j][k] + v)));
  }
};
```